# Can HTML be rendered when sent as a sms

Tags: android, html, android-intent, view, sms

I want to check whether html can be rendered properly and displayed when a html say . If possible how can I do achieve that in Android

Answer (score 0):

Displaying HTML inside an SMS is not possible